# Почему в бд с готовой таблицей не добавляется строка? js

Tags: javascript, html, база-данных, веб-программирование, html5

```
   <html>
    <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

  db = openDatabase("hashes", "0.1", "hashe", 20000);
if(!db){alert("Failed to connect to database.");}
;
asd=2222;
db.transaction(function(tx) {
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO hashes (hash) values(?)", [asd], null, null);
});

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: "не работает" - не поделитесь Вашим пониманием значения этого слова?

Comment: Ничего не выводит .

Comment: `db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM ToDo", [], function(tx, result) {
          console.log("SUCCESS", result.rows.length, result); // добавьте вывод в консоль
          for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
            document.write('<b>' + result.rows.item(i)['label'] + '</b><br />');
          }
        }, function(tx, error) { // добавьте обработчик ошибок
          console.log("ERROR", error); 
        });
      }); `

Что в консоли браузера?

Comment: Я что-то пропустил? С каких это пор клиентский Javascript работает с объектами за пределами браузера?

Comment: @Димка , пропустил, да. 7 лет пропустил - https://habrahabr.ru/post/84654/

Comment: Да пример я брал с этого поста на хабре. Но он не работает у меня. Ничего не выводит на странице ,ошибок никаких не показывает.

Comment: Не постесняюсь спросить, а сама база и таблица созданы?

Comment: @Димка функция должна сама создать если не найдет. Но я и  создавал вручную и прописывал все для проверки бд.